# Python Selenium .click method doesn't work

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to click a button with the `.click` method, but if I type `.cl`, my IDE doesn’t even suggest the `.click` function. The Chrome window opens but then after that, Python throws an error. I added two pictures - in the first, you can see my code, and in the second, you can see the error that is thrown:

[image: the two windows]

Comment: find_elements_by_xpath will return a list. You'll want to run click on an element in the list returned by that method

Comment: it's important to note that Python is not case-insensitive; the function should be `click()` not `Click()`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please avoid posting images (or worse, links to images) of code or errors. Anything text-based (code and errors) should be posted as text directly in the question itself and formatted properly. You can get more [formatting help here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). You can also read about [why you shouldn't post images/links of code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the error, Python tries to access the `Click` attribute for a `list` object. This is happening because the [.find_elements_by_xpath() method returns a list](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html).

Therefore, the solution for your problem would be to pull an item from that list and use the `click` method on it, rather than on the list itself.

```py
sb[0].click()
```

Comment: if there's only element could use find_element_by_xpath() instead of find_elements_by_xpath()

Comment: True, although OP didn't specify a guarantee that it will return only 1 element.